# Importing contacts from old dumb phone

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, import

My mom uses an ancient [Samsung SGH-C140](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_c140-1830.php) dumb phone with a mini SIM that has 150 contacts capacity. However all her contacts are stored on the phone, and there are around 400 of them. After all these years I have *finally* managed to convince her to allow me to buy a new phone for her (that too only when the keypad of the old one has given way)!

Now the problem is that the new Android phone uses a micro SIM, and I'm at a complete loss as to how to go about transferring those 400-odd contacts to it.

The only option I could think of was to go get the mini SIM cut to micro SIM size, then repeatedly use the **Copy All Contacts to SIM** feature to transfer from the old phone to SIM (while using the outer mini SIM sized bracket), and then from the SIM (without the bracket) to the new phone. The problem with this method is that the Samsung phone doesn't allow me to select the contacts, and always copies the same set of 150 contacts to the SIM before complaining about lack of space. (Aargh, which idiot made this phone's software?!)

Since I simply can't afford the loss of any of the contacts, what do I do? Do I *really* have no other option than to sit and manually read and enter all those contacts again?

P.S. I thought briefly about checking on some sort of PC software for the ancient phone, but even if it exists and can run on Windows 7/8.1/10, I have no clue where I'd get the required phone-to-PC cable from at a reasonable price.

Edit: OK, so the [UK site for the phone](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/SGH-C140IAACRO) mentions **Samsung PC Studio Image Editor** and **Samsung PC Studio Internet Access**. I assume the latter is the one that *might* support contacts export, but aside from the cable issue, there's the additional problem of how I would even export those contacts using the software to a format that Android would understand. If the software supports export/import of contacts using some proprietary format only from/to the phone itself, then there's obviously no point using it.

Comment: If you click on the 'more' in the link you'll see a program called `Samsung PC Studio PIMS/File Manager` which might be the one that handles contacts export.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Thank you, I missed that. It does sound promising, although if if it cannot export to VCF or something Android can handle then it would be pointless. Even if it can, I'm still stuck when it comes to obtaining the proper cable. Couldn't find it being sold online by any seller in my country unfortunately. Just have to keep searching I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

One possible option, if you can be sure which 150 contacts are being copied to the SIM in the old phone, is to transfer 150 contacts, copy them to the smart phone, and *delete them from the old phone*.  Then, next cycle, you'll get the next 150, and in twenty minutes or so you'll be done.  The trick is being sure you're deleting the same contacts that were transferred to the SIM.

Comment: You see, the problem with this as I mentioned is that it isn't allowing me to select the contacts to be copied. So I'd have to copy 150 contacts, then check each contact on the new phone, find it on the old phone and delete it. Once I've done that 150 times, I'd have to do the whole SIM dance again to copy the next set of 150. Frankly I think I'd find pulling out my hair one by one a more pleasant experience. Sigh... I'm really struggling with this and have a sinking feeling I'll have to do the whole damn thing manually. **Aren't there any SIMs available with more RAM to store more contacts?**

Comment: @David there are larger memory SIMs, but if either of the phones are locked to a carrier they will not work.

Comment: @EthanZ: Carrier locking is extremely rare here. How do I get my hands on one of these super SIMs? Wikipedia says "SIM cards can come in various data capacities, from 8 KB to at least 256 KB. All allow a maximum of 250 contacts to be stored on the SIM". If that's true then I'll still be in the same boat. I was hoping there would be a SIM with a capacity of 400 or 500 contacts.